# jQuery mouseover and mouseleave - when I hover with the mouse on an element multiple times, the effect will play more than once

Tags: jquery, html, css

When I hover with the mouse on an element multiple times, the effect will play more than once. (that's normal for mouseover).

I should use .hover() instead, but I don't know how to do that in my situation.

```js
/*Portal MATE - jQuery*/
    $("#cursuri-mate").mouseenter(function () {
        $(".cursuri-text-mate").animate({
            opacity: 0.0,
            top: "-=50",
        }, 600);
        $(".fa-book").animate({
            opacity: 0.0,
            top: "-=50",
        }, 600);
        $(".selectie-clasa-mate-cursuri").animate({
            opacity: 1.0,
            top: "-=50",
        }, 600);
        $(".hidden-cursuri").animate({
            opacity: 1.0,
            top: "-=50",
        }, 600);
    });
    $("#cursuri-mate").mouseleave(function () {
        $(".cursuri-text-mate").animate({
            opacity: 1,
            top: "+=50",
        }, 300);
        $(".fa-book").animate({
            opacity: 1,
            top: "+=50",
        }, 300);
        $(".selectie-clasa-mate-cursuri").animate({
            opacity: 0.0,
            top: "+=50",
        }, 300);
        $(".hidden-cursuri").animate({
            opacity: 0.0,
            top: "+=50",
        }, 300);
    });
```

```css
/*CSS PENTRU INDEX.HTML*/
/*CSS PENTRU INDEX.HTML*/
/*CSS PENTRU INDEX.HTML*/
/*CSS PENTRU INDEX.HTML*/
/*CSS PENTRU INDEX.HTML*/

body {
    width: 100%;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility; /*setam textul sa fie optimzat pentru o lizbilitate mai buna, in detrimentul vitezei de incarcare si a preciziei geometrice*/
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    height: 100%;
}

@keyframes tranzitie-inceput {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
}

.index-mate-poza {
    z-index: 1;
}

#mate, #info {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 5rem;
  text-transform: uppercase; /*transformam textul in MAJUSCULE*/
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #429ba8;
  height: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

#mate {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #D3D3D3; /*inseram un border gri, subtire, ce va avea efectul de umbra/diferentiere a celor 2 jumatati*/
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 0, #429ba8 65%), url(../img/mate.jpg);
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999;
    text-align: center;
}

#mate:before {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        z-index: 10;
        background: url(../img/mate.jpg);
        opacity: 0;
        transition: all 1s;
        z-index: 1;
}

#mate:hover:before {
        opacity: 1;
        z-index: 1;
}

#info {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 0, #87cebf 65%), url(../img/info.jpg);
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999;
    text-align: center;
}

#info:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    background: url(../img/info.jpg);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 1s;
    z-index: 1;
}

#info:hover:before {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 1;
}

#container-index {
    height: 100vh; /*div-ul container va fi egal cu toata inaltimea viewport-ului, ceea ce va face ca continutul sa fie la fel de mare ca suprafata vizibila a device-ului utilizatorului*/
    animation-name: tranzitie-inceput;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    user-select: none; /*dezactivam selectia utilizatorului*/
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden; /*dezactivam scrollbar-urile in cazul in care continutul depaseste "element's box"*/
}

.text-mate {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%); /*centram textul VERTICAL in interiorul parintelui #MATE*/
}

.text-info {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%); /*centram textul VERTICAL in interiorul parintelui #INFO*/
}

.hover { /*pregatim clasa ce se va adauga div-ului peste care trecem cu mouse-ul, utilizand jQuery*/
    transition: 2s; /*folosim un efect incet in care elementul se mareste*/
    height: 75% !important;
}

.default { /*pregatim clasa ce se va adauga celuilalt div fata de cel pe care se trece mouse-ul, utilizand jQuery*/
    transition: 1.5s;
    height: 50% !important; /*folosim un efect rapid in care se va ajunge la forma initiala*/
}

.not-hovered-on { /*pregatim clasa ce se va adauga celuilalt div fata de cel pe care se trece mouse-ul, utilizand jQuery*/
    transition: 2s; 
    height: 25% !important; /*folosim un efect incet in care elementul se micsoreaza*/
}

/*CSS PENTRU PAGINA-MATE.HTML*/
/*CSS PENTRU PAGINA-MATE.HTML*/
/*CSS PENTRU PAGINA-MATE.HTML*/
/*CSS PENTRU PAGINA-MATE.HTML*/
/*CSS PENTRU PAGINA-MATE.HTML*/
/*CSS PENTRU PAGINA-MATE.HTML*/
/*CSS PENTRU PAGINA-MATE.HTML*/

#container-mate {
    background-color: #e6e7d0;
}

/*HEADER-UL PAGINII*/

#meniu-mate {
    max-width: 1500px;
    margin: 0 auto; /*meniul este centrat orizontal*/
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 100%;
}

.mate-sus {
    height: 10rem;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #7ec7bc, #4ca2ab 35%, #429ba8);
}

.mate-sus-nerd {
    float: right;
    width: 9%;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    margin-right: 65px;
}

.citat-mate-sus {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: 85px;
}

.selector-portal {
    height: 3rem;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #9bddc5, #34bab8);
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.selector-portal > ul {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        margin-left: 1.5rem;
        font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.selector-portal > ul > li {
        display: inline;
}

.selector-portal > ul > li > a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #fff;
        font-style: italic;  
}

/*CONTINUTUL PAGINII*/

#cursuri-mate {
    height: 12rem;
    max-width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #429ba8;
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.cursuri-text-mate {
    font-size: 4rem;
    position: relative;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: 4rem;
}

.selectie-clasa-mate-cursuri,
.selectie-clasa-mate-exercitii, 
.selectie-clasa-mate-quiz {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    margin-left: 2rem;
    opacity: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.cifre-clasa {
    float: right;
    display: inline;
}

.cifre-clasa > ul {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    margin-right: 50px;
}

.home {
   float: left;
   position: relative;
   top: 50%;
   transform: translateY(-50%);
   margin-left: 2rem;
   font-size: 2rem;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #fff;
   transition: 1s;
}

.home:hover {
        color: #429ba8;
}

.comutare-mate {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    margin-right: 2rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    transition: 1s;
}

.comutare-mate:hover {
        color: #429ba8;
}

.cifre-clasa > ul > li {
        opacity: 0;
        margin: 5px;
        display: inline-block;
}

.cifre-clasa > ul > li > a > img {
        width: 85%;
}

.cifre {
    width: 35%;
    margin-left: 400px;
    margin-top: -55px;
}

.fa-book {
    color: black;
    position: relative;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    top: 50%;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 2rem;
    font-size: 6rem;
}

#exercitii-mate {
    height: 12rem;
    max-width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #429ba8;
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.exercitii-text-mate {
    font-size: 4rem;
    position: relative;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: 4rem;
}

#quiz-mate {
    height: 12rem;
    max-width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #429ba8;
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.quiz-text-mate {
    font-size: 4rem;
    position: relative;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: 4rem;
}

.fa-pencil-alt {
    color: black;
    position: relative;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    top: 50%;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 2rem;
    font-size: 6rem;
}

.fa-question {
    color: black;
    position: relative;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    top: 50%;
    float: right;
    font-size: 6rem;
    margin-right: 2rem;
}

.fa-lightbulb {
    color: black;
    position: relative;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    top: 50%;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 2rem;
    font-size: 6rem;
}

#variante-mate {
    height: 12rem;
    max-width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #429ba8;
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.variante-text-mate {
    font-size: 4rem;
    position: relative;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: 4rem;
}

.fa-pencil-alt {
    color: black;
    position: relative;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    top: 50%;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 2rem;
}

/*FOOTER*/

.mate-jos {
    background-color: #28494e;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    text-align: right;
    height: 12.2rem;
    position: relative;
}

#contact-footer {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 6rem;
}

#contact-footer i {
        font-size: 5rem;
        margin-right: 5rem;
        margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.logo-mateinfo {
    float: left;
    width: 7%;
    left: 5%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; 
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
}

.footer-social {
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 14%;
    right: 5%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<article id="cursuri-mate">
                <i class="fa fa-book"></i>
                <h1 class="cursuri-text-mate">Cursuri</h1>
                <h1 class="selectie-clasa-mate-cursuri">Selecteaza clasa:</h1>
                <nav class="cifre-clasa">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="hidden-cursuri"><a href="#"><img src="img/9.png" /></a></li>
                        <li class="hidden-cursuri"><a href="#"><img src="img/10.png" /></a></li>
                        <li class="hidden-cursuri"><a href="#"><img src="img/11.png" /></a></li>
                        <li class="hidden-cursuri"><a href="#"><img src="img/12.png" /></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </article>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I think .hover() with .toggleClass() would be a better idea, but I don't know how. Should I make new classes for adding opacity, top and transition:? I tried to but when I take the mouse out of the element it wasn't behaving like it is now.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead jquery make it in css.
try this: work well for me

```
   .cursuri-text-mate, .fa-book, .selectie-clasa-mate-cursuri, .hidden-cursuri{
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    }

    #cursuri-mate:hover>.cursuri-text-mate, #cursuri-mate:hover>.fa-book{
        opacity: 0;
        top: -50px;
        transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
    }
    #cursuri-mate:hover>.selectie-clasa-mate-cursuri, #cursuri-mate:hover .hidden-cursuri{
        opacity: 1;
        top: -50px;
        transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
    }
```

Comment: Changing the second top: -50px with top:+50px made it the same effect. Thanks a lot.